# Extract sentences from beginning of news in single document summarization

Tags: nlp, text-mining, automatic-summarization

I am working on Single Document Summarization task on News datasets. I do some experiments in this task. A simple experiment that I make and has a good result is extracting sentences just from beginning of news. Now I want to find any paper or research result about this type of sentence selection.

Is there any research to show how good is to choose sentences just from beginning of text without any reordering?

Comment: So essentially you want to get the gist of the paragraph and you observed that picking the first sentence yields good results?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find research on that since it is overly simplistic. You can get started doing something more advanced for free via this API: https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/nlp/Summarizer

Comment: @HimaVarsha exactly.

Comment: @CalZ One of my friend told me he read something like that and DUC stopped challenging Single-document task for this problem.

Comment: What is DUC? http://duc.nist.gov/data.html ?

Comment: Hi, if my answer clarified your understanding of first sentence method, may I ask you to upvote my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Keselman, Schubert

### [Computational models for text summarization](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/reports/2749103.pdf)

The paper deals with methods (models) for text summarization. The reference (base) model was "first sentence model":

> As a baseline for our models we used a trivial model that repeats the
>   first sentence of the input document.

Then, various experiments and results are presented, like this one: (notice that "first sentence model" is always present as "baseline")

[image]

Moreover, one of the datasets for training and evaluation of models in this paper is [DUC](http://duc.nist.gov/data.html), which may be interesting to you.

---

Steinberger *(doctoral Thesis, 2005)*

### [Text Summarization within the LSA Framework](https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwib9NzHvPTTAhVDWCwKHdhnCWUQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftextmining.zcu.cz%2Fpublications%2FPhDThesis-Steinberger.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGCVVwQRrkYAnYNp5uWs3h_Sc51nQ&sig2=Q1pgh3Lpx_1NY7d0VJFvtg)

In section 2.1, the author discusses document summarization approaches based on sentence extraction. He identifies five approaches:

- Surface Level Approaches
- Corpus-based Approaches
- Cohesion-based Approaches
- Rhetoric-based Approaches
- Graph-based Approaches

(The "First Sentence Approach" belongs to the *Surface Level Approaches") The author further describes these approaches and compares them.

---

Khodra, Widyantoro, Aziz, Trilaksono *(Journal of ICT Research and Applications, 2011)*

### [Free Model of Sentence Classifier for Automatic Extraction of Topic Sentences](http://journals.itb.ac.id/index.php/jictra/article/download/205/199)

The author identifies and tests methods for identifying the most important sentences in a text (see list of 58 items below, called features). Surprisingly, in the conclusion, it is said that position of the sentence is a dominant feature, meaning that including all other features into consideration leads only to small improvement.

1. position
2. sentence length
3. number of words before a main verb
4. adjective incidence
5. existential there incidence
6. incidence of 3rd person singular grammatical form
7. anaphora incidence
8. coordinators incidence
9. cardinal number incidence
10. incidence of past tense endings
11. Hypernymy
12. Polysemy
13. concreteness index
14. affect_formulai
15. bad_formulaic
16. comparison_formulaic
17. continue_formulaic
18. contrast_formulaic
19. detail_formulaic
20. future_formulaic
21. gap_formulaic
22. good_formulaic
23. here_formulaic
24. in_order_to_formulaic
25. method_formulaic
26. no_textstructure_formulaic
27. similarity_formulaic
28. them_formulaic
29. textstructure_formulaic
30. tradition_formulaic
31. us_previous_formulaic
32. affect
33. argumentation
34. better_solution
35. change
36. comparison
37. continue
38. contrast
39. interest
40. need
41. presentation
42. problem
43. research
44. solution
45. textstructure
46. use
47. copula
48. aim_ref_agent
49. gap_agent
50. general_agent
51. problem_agent
52. ref_agent
53. ref_us_agent
54. solution_agent
55. textstructure_agent
56. them_agent
57. them_pronoun_agent
58. us_agent

For you, the most important part of the paper may be table 5:

[image]

Read carefully the explanation of the table in the paper, and the whole Section 4.3.

---

Other papers worth examining:

---

Luhn *(1958)*

### [The Automatic Creation of Literature Abstracts](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i256/f06/papers/luhn58.pdf)

---

Kupiec, Pedersen, Chen *(1995)*

### [A Trainable Document Summarizer](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i256/f06/papers/kupiec95.pdf)

---

Yang, Pedersen *(1997)*

### [A Comparative Study on Feature Selection in Text Categorization](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i256/f06/papers/yang97comparative.pdf)

---

Sebastiani *(2002)*

### [Machine Learning in Automated Text Categorization](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i256/f06/papers/sebastiani02.pdf)

---

Answer (score 0):

Before evaluating how good is [automatic summarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization) by taking the first sentence, you should decide how to evaluate summarization.

In supervised learning typically it is easy to know if the prediction match the concept - they should be identical. Upon that, you can choose a metric that fits your needs (e.g., accuracy, precision, recall) and compare classifiers.

The problem of evaluating text summarization is that deciding whether a summarization is good is subjective and prone to error.

A possible metric is [ROUGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROUGE_(metric)) which is a set of heuristics (e.g., common longest subsequence) that compare the summary to the original text.
Note that having a good ROUGE score is an estimation but an estimation that will enable you to benchmark your algorithm agains others. See [EVALUATION MEASURES FOR TEXT
SUMMARIZATION](http://www.cai.sk/ojs/index.php/cai/article/viewFile/37/24) by Josef Steinberger, Karel Jeˇzek for a discussion of metrics and other algorithms.
Showing that you get a good score with respect to an algorithm that is based on cue words will be a good results.

Another possibility is building a gold standard by comparing the first sentence to the text and manually labeling it for a good summary.
While manually labeling will give you good estimates of the performance of your algorithm, it costly in term of time.
A more severe disadvantage id that this gold standard is fitted to your algorithm and hard to use for other algorithms. Suppose that the second sentence is just as good algorithm as the first one. The gold standard built for the first sentence won't be able to show that.

For a good estimation I suggest that you will use ROUGE for comparison and a gold standard for absolute results. If you have the resources to create a gold standard for the benchmark algorithms, the comparison will become much more robust.

Comment: I never asked for evaluation measures. clearly I'm looking for a paper that mentioned if we have e news dataset like DUC, selecting sentences ordering by index of them has a good result (high ROUGE-1 for example)

Comment: I'm not familiar with such a paper.